# Identify plant with tubular pink flowers and paired elliptic leaves

Tags: identification, flowers

Help in naming pink flower, cottage garden plant.  Have tried numerous books and internet for identification.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome Jillia!  It's great to meet you! Thanks for joining us, and for caring enough to post your answer. We do indeed need a picture to keep the question from being [closed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), but our system is very tricky, so it's not your fault.  I'll walk you through it, then if you're getting an error message of some kind, let us know what it says. Also, if you have it on another website, like a Google photo album or something, you can post the link, or just leave a note and one of us will download it for you. I hope this helps!

Comment: To go back into the question and post the picture, first press the gray edit word under the text, or this [edit]. Then, press the symbol on the top row that sort of looks like a picture of a mountain. (It's next to the brackets.) A big box will open giving you an option to either Drag and Drop your photo or post a link from the web. To post a link, click on those words and a box will open for you to put the link address. After doing either one of those things, click on "Add Picture" which is on the bottom right of that box. If that doesn't work, leave us a note as to what happened!

Comment: Jillia, our system is different from others, so I invite you to visit our [help] if you haven't already. [Ask] is a good place to start. There are the rules for [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) questions. Again, we're glad you're here and hope you'll stay and keep contributing.

Answer (score 4):

Plant is [Strobilanthes flaccidifolius](http://www.igarden.com.au/plant-type.jsp?t=strobilanthes&id=92). I received the name via text message from a friend who saw my question.